# How to split date and time from string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

I have a dataset from excel imported in pandas. There is a one column date and time in string format.

```
16-MAR-16 11.35.27.000000000 AM
05-APR-16 05.21.14.000000000 PM
16-FEB-16 09.56.36.000000000 AM
16-MAR-16 11.35.27.000000000 AM
16-MAR-16 09.28.11.000000000 AM
19-MAY-16 03.50.38.000000000 PM
```

I want to split this data into date and time into different columns. I have gone through a couple of the same questions but could not find an answer.

This codes that I tried

```
(1)df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Invoice Date'],dayfirst = True)

(Error)File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.py", line 559, in parse
raise ValueError("Unknown string format")
ValueError: Unknown string format


(2)from datetime import datetime

df["timestamp"] = df["Invoice Date"].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,"dd-mmm-yy hh.mm.ss.%f aa"))

(Error)  ValueError: time data '16-MAR-16 11.35.27.000000000 AM' does not match format 'dd-mmm-yy hh.mm.ss.%f aa'
```

Please help me out here.

Comment: Check the python strftime reference http://strftime.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parameter `format`, [reference](http://strftime.org/):

```
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Invoice Date'], format='%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%f %p')
print (df)

                      Invoice Date           timestamp
0  16-MAR-16 11.35.27.000000000 AM 2016-03-16 11:35:27
1  05-APR-16 05.21.14.000000000 PM 2016-04-05 05:21:14
2  16-FEB-16 09.56.36.000000000 AM 2016-02-16 09:56:36
3  16-MAR-16 11.35.27.000000000 AM 2016-03-16 11:35:27
4  16-MAR-16 09.28.11.000000000 AM 2016-03-16 09:28:11
5  19-MAY-16 03.50.38.000000000 PM 2016-05-19 03:50:38
```

If want 2 separate columns for dates and times:

```
d = pd.to_datetime(df['Invoice Date'], format='%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%f %p')
df['date'] = d.dt.date
df['time'] = d.dt.time
print (df)

                      Invoice Date        date      time
0  16-MAR-16 11.35.27.000000000 AM  2016-03-16  11:35:27
1  05-APR-16 05.21.14.000000000 PM  2016-04-05  05:21:14
2  16-FEB-16 09.56.36.000000000 AM  2016-02-16  09:56:36
3  16-MAR-16 11.35.27.000000000 AM  2016-03-16  11:35:27
4  16-MAR-16 09.28.11.000000000 AM  2016-03-16  09:28:11
5  19-MAY-16 03.50.38.000000000 PM  2016-05-19  03:50:38
```

Comment: how come you know so much pandas...i see almost all questions being answered by you....do you have a good resource to master pandas

Comment: @jezrael OP clearly asked "I want to split this data into date and time in different columns.",

Comment: @vks - Yes, If I have time I try answer.

Comment: looks better :)